# Renamed and Transferred site successful but old Social Media links are broken

Tags: wordpress, seo, http-status-code-404, web-hosting, http-status-code-301

I just got finished with moving my site from one domain name to another. All old links on social media and search engines are broken. If I click on a link from reddit or Facebook it still points to oldwebsite.com. Even though if I type oldwebsite.com into a browser, newwebsite.com does pop up. Is there anyway I can resolve this issue? All I did was export the old site data, switched to the new site, and imported the new site back. What am I missing now?

Google is coming with weird results when I search for this topic. I am using godaddy and wordpress with over 500 posts if it matters. Thank you.

Comment: oldwebsite.com/someurl should issue a 301 redirect to newwebsite.com/someurl. For how long depends on SEO, which the folks at [webmasters.se] know all about.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think I should post the problem there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding the social media links in the template files like footer.php of header.php

please double check once again.

If you change site_url in wp-admin in also and if the social media links loading from templates then it wont reflect the old site to new site

Comment: I'm sorry but these are not links on the website. These are links shared out to social media. I previously shared out these links on sites like Reddit and Facebook. Now that I have moved the site, those previous links are not being redirected.